# loop rate of a subscriber?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
How can i find the loop rate of a subscriber/subscriber callback ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267121/loop-rate-of-a-subscriber-?/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2017-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Subsciber callbacks are called whenever new message arrives to the topics however you can print the frequency of messages by command: rostopic hz /topic_name

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [orko](https://answers.ros.org/users/30575/orko/) with karma: 91 on 2017-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on 2017-07-22**:
Hi Orko,
Thank you for your comment. I am thinking of finding rate at which subscriber call back function is executed. Is  it the same as "rostopic hz /topic_name" ?

**Comment by [orko](https://answers.ros.org/users/30575/orko/) on 2017-07-22**:
Technically, yes (assuming your subscriber doesn't miss any message). You can test this simply printing the ros time inside the callback and then calculating frequency by 1/(consecutive ros time in secs). (I know it's a dummy way but it's simplest) It would give the same value with rostopic hz